# Get span text using CSS Selector (with xpath this works fine)

Tags: selenium

So i have this element:

```
<span class="clas">Create new form</span>
```

And i want to get this elemen:

```
span:contains('Create new')
```

Why this is not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your selector, I assume that you are trying to use the `:contains()` CSS pseudo-class selector, which *has been removed* from the CSS3 spec.  This won't work because the latest browsers conform to the new CSS standards.

If the `class` attribute for this specific element is unique, then you can use:

```
span.clas
```

If not, then you are forced to use xpath:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Create new')]
```

Comment: Nice explanation.