# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"

Tags: python, css, selenium, exception, css-selectors

I am working on selenium python in firefox. I am trying to find element by css selector

```
element = "span:contains('Control panel')"
my_driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element)
```

I am getting below error

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "span:contains('Control panel')" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: 'span:contains('Control panel')' is not a valid selector: "span:contains('Control panel')"
```

In selenium IDE I am successfully able to find element by this field but in Python it is not working

Comment: have you checked your css selector with any browser. I guess, the contains will not work in css

Comment: Share your HTML code -- I will help you try CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `css_selector` to locate element by text is not supported in Selenium (although it will work in the developer tools console). The only possibility is `xpath`

```
element = "//span[contains(text(), 'Control panel')]"
my_driver.find_element_by_xpath(element)
```

Edit: a comment by @FlorentB:

> A `css selector` is not supported by the console either, but JQuery supports it. The `$('...')` from the console is a shorthand for `document.querySelector` which is generally overridden with JQuery when the page has it.

Comment: Can you help me with multiple conditions if css selector is css=a.actionicon:contains('Create access policy'). What is xpath for that

Comment: @Nitesh `"//a[@class='actionicon'][contains(text(), 'Create access policy')]"`

Comment: @Guy, a CSS selector is not supported by the console either, but JQuery supports it. The `$('...')` from the console is a shorthand for `document.querySelector` which is generally overridden with JQuery when the page has it.

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "span:contains('Control panel')" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: 'span:contains('Control panel')' is not a valid selector: "span:contains('Control panel')"
```

As per [**`Issue#987`**](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/987) and [**`Issue#1547`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1547):

> **`The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).`**

The pseudo-class was specific to the **`Sizzle Selector Engine`** that `Selenium 1.0` relied on. But, it was decided that **`WebDriver`** was not going to support the **`Sizzle`** style `CSS selectors` that `Selenium 1.0` used.

Now, an interesting fact is the **:contains** **`pseudo-class`** will work for browsers that don't natively support CSS selectors (IE7, IE8, etc) which causes
inconsistencies between browsers and selectors.

Hence a better solution would have been to go with any other attribute of the `<span>` tag as follows :

```
element = "span[attribute_name=attribute_value]"
```

---

### Alternate Solution

You can use either of the following **xpaths** as per the prevailing [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes):

- Using **`text()`**:

  ```
  element = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Control panel']")
  ```
- Using **`contains()`**:

  ```
  element = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Control panel')]")
  ```
- Using **`normalize-space()`**:

  ```
  element = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Control panel']")
  ```

---

### Using  jQuery

You can also use *jQuery* as follows:

```
$('span:contains("Control panel")')
```

---

### Trivia :

A valuable comment from @FlorentB.

> **CSS selector is not supported by the console either, but `JQuery` supports it. The `$('...')` from the console is a shorthand for `document.querySelector` which is generally overridden with `JQuery` when the page has it.**