# not a valid selector error while running selenium via python

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on save button. I am using firefox. I have tried below target in firefox IDE which is working as expected there

```
css=div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Yes, ')
```

However, When I am trying to find it in python using below command, it is failing

```
element = div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Yes, ')
my_driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element).click()
```

I am getting below error

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Yes, ')" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: 'div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Yes, ')' is not a valid selector: "div.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Yes, ')"
```

Any clues. What is the respective xpath value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception)

Comment: Using css `contains` is dangerous. I have seen it fail in many cases.

Comment: Could you pls provide the structure of the button? HTML and CSS.

Comment: contains function is not supported in selenium css selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath for this

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ui-dialog-buttonset')]/button[contains(text(),'Yes, ')]")
```