# How to target a specific input text field in Selenium using CSS selector based on the label name

Tags: css, selenium

I have a web page having about 9 input fields having differnt label names and I GOOGLED a lot to get the answer but was not successful. Please help me with the CSS selector, with xpath i'm able to arrive at the solution but not with CSS and we have to use CSS in our project.

My sample html looks something like this:

```
<div class="no match found for this class name">
  <div class="no match found for this class name too">
    <label>1st label Name </label>
    <div class="7 matching nodes found for this class name">
      <input class="3 matching nodes found for this class name" type="text" value="dynamic int value">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your label does not have a name. It has an inner text..which is not selectable by CSS.

Comment: you can try this css div[class*="no match found for this class name too"] label

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: Can you share your xpath?

Comment: @AnkurSingh: Thanks, this helps me identify the label but drill down further to the respective input field is being a challenge!!! Will try and post my code if it works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select the text between the elements in css...However you can pass a different class for every label and then select the input with `+` css selector.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
label[class="label1"]+div>input {
  background: red;
}

label[class="label2"]+div>input {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="no match found for this class name">
  <div class="no match found for this class name too">
    <label class="label1">1st label Name</label>
    <div class="7 matching nodes found for this class name">
      <input class="3 matching nodes found for this class name" type="text" value="dynamic int value">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="no match found for this class name too">
    <label class="label2">2nd label Name</label>
    <div class="7 matching nodes found for this class name">
      <input class="3 matching nodes found for this class name" type="text" value="dynamic int value">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use a data attribute as I don't think name is a valid attribute for a label

Comment: @Pete no other attribute available

Comment: @Bhuwan nope no name given to the label, direct text within the <label>tags

Comment: @SavithaB.S You can't select the text within the elements using css....you can use a class instead...See updated answer above..

Answer (score 0):

To target the following `<input>` tag with `CSS` you can use the following line of code :

```
"div.no_match_found_for_this_class_name > div.no_match_found_for_this_class_name_too label:contains('1st label Name') div:nth-child(1) > input.3_matching_nodes_found_for_this_class_name[type='text']"
```

### Analysis

- As per the `HTML` as the `<label>` tag have only `innerText` and you have to construct a `CSS selector` based on the label name so we have to use **`:contains pseudo-class`**
- Note that as per the QA [**`stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

  ```
  The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the current CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome.
  ```