# Unable to find correct Target selector to click an element

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-ide

Please see the image below which shows code of the web page in Developer Tools window and advise me the correct selector for 'Depreciation Models'. Text highlighted in red is constant, however the surrounding text is dynamic. So I tried using **contains** selector to locate but unsuccessful. I want to avoid XPATH as number of before and after div elements may keep changing.

I am using Selenium IDE hence the C#/Java code for RC/Webdriver won't help much.

[image: Web Page Code in Developer Tools]

Selenium IDE generated target path is this:

```
css=#dhxId_rgWATog7lC3E_27572|6059|6152 > td.sub_item_text > div.sub_item_text
```

I tried

```
css=contains('27572') > td.sub_item_text > div.sub_item_text
```

but it didn't work.

Kindly suggest. I am stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tried the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as :

```
css=contains('27572') > td.sub_item_text > div.sub_item_text
```

### Reasons for not working

- From the snapshot of the HTML you have provided, **27572** is not the **innerText** but *partial string* of the `id` *attribute*.
- As per [**selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814):

> `The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).`

### Solution

You can use the following *xpath* as per the existing [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes):

```
xpath=//tr[@class='sub_item'][contains(@id,'27572')]//td[@class='sub_item_text']/div[@class='sub_item_text'][contains(.,'Depreciations Models')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be the right approach:

```
<style>
   [id*="27572"] > td.sub_item_text > div.sub_item_text{
      color:red;
   }
```

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="dhxId_rgWATog7lC3E_27572|6059|6152" class="sub_item">
                <td class="sub_item_icon">
                     <i class="fa fa-user epc-down-circled-2"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="sub_item_text">
                     <div class="sub_item_text"> Depriciations Models</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It will set all elements that have an id attribute value containing "27572" and inside of it.

Comment: Thanks slon. I don't want to highlight it in red. I will give it a shot and update you.

Comment: Red color or anything is up to you, you wanted to select it right? I just added red color as an example. It an be anything. Glad that works for you.

Comment: I used the same typed code that you have and it works.

Comment: is your css style reachable to your page?

Comment: I do not need css style. I need selector written for selenium IDE.