# Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to locate below link by using `a[text='This is a link']` and `a[innertext='This is a link']` but both of them are not working.

I know this can be achieved by using XPath or other ways, but I am curious why CSS Selector that I have used is not working. refer this [link](http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/).

```
<a title="seleniumframework" href="http://www.seleniumframework.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to locate a link by using the following **CssSelector**s:

- `a[text='This is a link']`
- `a[innertext='This is a link']`

As per [**`Issue#987`**](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/987) and [**`Issue#1547`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1547):

> **`The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).`**

You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

### Solution

As per the HTML you can use either of the following solutions:

- *CssSelector* using the attribute `title`:

  ```
  "a[title='seleniumframework']"
  ```
- *CssSelector* using the attribute `href`:

  ```
  "a[href='http://www.seleniumframework.com']"
  ```
- *CssSelector* using the attributes `title` and `href`:

  ```
  "a[title='seleniumframework'][href='http://www.seleniumframework.com']"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The right CSS Selector for your case is:

```
a[title="seleniumframework"]
```

or

```
a[href="http://www.seleniumframework.com"]
```

You can also use this one: `a[target="_blank"]`, but the ones above are more unique.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to use attribute selector, you can only select from available attributes that the hyperlink element currently has.

**text** is not available attribute in html so selecting it this way through css will not work.Rather you should try to use other attribute like a[title=seleniumframework] for example.

Comment: then how this //a[text()='This is a link'] xpath with text works?

Comment: @J_Coder `text()` in XPath is not *an attribute*, but a *function that returns text node*