# Unable to find CSS selector by :contains()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Unable to find CSS selector using `:contains()`.

[image]

I have followed the instructions from https://www.browserstack.com/guide/css-selectors-in-selenium
at #5 – Inner text
but still, no result is shown, Can someone please help me/Tell me how to find Web element using text, CSS only

Here is Sample Dom

```
<ul id='id'>
    <li class='class'>
        <a class='class_class2' href="/Myaccount/summary">"Summary"</a>
    <li class='class'>
        <a class='class_class2' href="/Myaccount/Profile">"Profile"</a> 
</ul>
```

Here : `a:contains('Summary')`

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781167/6793637

Contains: is no longer available

you should use `xpath` to find elements using `innerText`

```
xpath:

   //a[contains(text(),"Summary")]
```

You can get exact match as

```
   //a[text()="Summary"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)
- [Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351028/finding-link-using-text-in-css-selector-is-not-working/53355811#53355811)

---

### Alternative

To locate the element with text as **Summary** you can use either of the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

- Using `first-child`:

  ```
  ul#id li:first-child > a
  ```
- Using `nth-child()`:

  ```
  ul#id > li:nth-child(1) > a
  ```

---

### tl; dr

References:

- [CSS selector :contains doesn't work with Selenium 2.0a7](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/987)
- [css pseudo-class :contains() no longer allows anchors](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1547)