# Python Selenium get element by CSS matching text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

Hi I can't figure out how to get an element by CSS and matching with text. I know it can be done with Xpath but I'd rather use CSS.

```
<div class="button-face">
  <div class="button-face-caption"> Text I want to find 1</div>
</div>
<div class="button-face">
  <div class="button-face-caption"> Text I want to find 2</div>
</div>
```

So in by CSS would be something like...

`driver.find_element_by_css('div.button-face-caption')`

But how can add the text matching to that? i tried with `contains` and `innerText` and none seem to work.

Comment: Why the preference for css in this case?

Comment: @trickymuffin Can you update the HTML with the parent element of `<div class="button-face">`?

Answer (score 1):

As you said it's supported in xpath:

This would be a solution with an xpath using `contains` and `text()`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="button-face-caption" and contains(text(),"Text I want to find")]')
```

The xpath being:

```
//div[@class="button-face-caption" and contains(text(),"Text I want to find")]
```

For css, look here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/362/34209 which should allow us to use:

```
div:contains('Text I want to find')
```

Which would lead us to

```
driver.find_element_by_css("div:contains('Text I want to find')")
```

However this comes with a [BIG caveat](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/362/a-way-to-match-on-text-using-css-locators#comment612_375):

> :contains() is not part of the current CSS3 specification so it will
> not work on all browsers, only ones that implemented it before it was
> pulled. (see w3.org/TR/css3-selectors)

Comment: ```driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div:contains('No, I need to create an account')").click()
         InvalidSelectorException: Message: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```
:(

Comment: which browser? As I stated, it's not actually valid CSS. I would just use xpath.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can create your own function

```
def find_by_css(selector, text=''):
    return [element for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector) if text in element.text][0]
```

Then you can call it as

```
find_by_css('div.button-face-caption')  # search only by CSS-selector
```

or

```
find_by_css('div.button-face-caption', 'Text I want to find 2')  # search by CSS + text
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the following discussions:

- [CSS selector :contains doesn't work with Selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/987)
- [css pseudo-class :contains() no longer allows anchors](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1547)

> **`The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).`**

---

### Solution

You need to consider the ancestor of the `<div class="button-face">` element and traverse down. Let us assume that both the `<div class="button-face">` are with in a parent `<div class="class">`:

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="button-face">
      <div class="button-face-caption"> Text I want to find 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-face">
      <div class="button-face-caption"> Text I want to find 2</>
    </div>
</div>
```

So to identify the element with text as:

- *Text I want to find 1*:

  ```
  div.class div:first-child > div.button-face-caption
  ```
- *Text I want to find 2*:

  ```
  div.class div:nth-child(2) > div.button-face-caption
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)
- [Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351028/finding-link-using-text-in-css-selector-is-not-working/53355811#53355811)