# Does CSS Selector have contains text similar to xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, css-selectors, automated-tests

In Selenium, are there any options for CSS selectors with "contains" similar to Xpath where we check with contains[text(),....].

In the following example, I have given the CSS and Xpath

```
<div class="abcjha">
  <span>
    <a class="test" ng-tracking="test1" data-tracking="abc">Daniel</a>
  </span>
</div>

CSS : a[data-tracking='abc']
Xpath : //div/span/a[contains(text(),'Daniel')]
```

Similar to Xpath above, is there an option in CSS to check for the inner text ?
When I browsed about it I saw this option

```
==> css=button:contains("Log In")
```

but it is not working for me.

Is there any option?

Answer (score 3):

No, [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) for [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) still doesn't supports `:contains("text")` method.

> You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:
>
> - [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884814/7429447)
> - [Finding link using text in CSS Selector is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355811/7429447)

Comment: what can you say about the second answer here? Is it correct? he says it is possible to locate web element based on it's text By.cssSelector with Selenium.

Comment: The author didn't provide any links to the docs/specs and I'm not sure if it is a speculation. Need some time to see the specs.

Comment: Please let me know if you checked that and have any new insights here

Comment: Sure. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The contains() pseudo-class may not work with browsers that don't natively support CSS selectors. Also, it has been deprecated from CSS3 specification.

so the alternative is using `innerText`

```
WebElement cell = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[innerText='Item 1']"));
```

or `textContent`

```
WebElement cell = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[textContent='Item 1']"));
```

Comment: Hi, According to the example in my question, I tried  a[textContent='Daniel'] also with innertext, it wouldnt recognize my element.

Comment: I tried to reach the parent and then the child,                                                 
This helped to reach the child                                                                       
             div.td>span>a                                                                   
 but when I add  innertext/textContent like                                                    
             div.td>span>a[innerText="Daniel AG"]                                                                 
  it wouldnt identify the element. Any help on this ?