# How to write CSS Selector using Inner Text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Can anyone help me with the css selector for the below element. Here there are multiple elements available with same class name. Please use inner text to form a css selector for this

```
<div class="title kpi-tile3-title o9-tooltip" data-o9title="Safety Stock">Safety Stock</div>
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.
Selenium CSS Selectors do not support locating elements based on their text content.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417122/does-css-selector-have-contains-text-similar-to-xpath) or other similar questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div:contains('Safety Stock')")
```

or this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-o9title='Safety Stock']")
```

Comment: contains is not working, Can you tell me how to do using inner text

Comment: Sorry, my mistake there, edited my answer.