# Unable to locate the element by CSS selector and Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

I am trying to locate this tag with CSS selector inner text

```
<a href="/introduction-to-selenium.html">1) Introduction</a>
```

I have used the xpath:

```
a.contains("1) Introduction")
```

But its not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `a.contains("")` is not `xpath` or `css selector`. You can't use `css selector` to locate by text in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using is not xpath one, the correct xpath selector would be like this:

```
//a[contains(string(), "1) Introduction")]
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *linkText*:

  ```
  1) Introduction
  ```
- *partialLinkText*:

  ```
  Introduction
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  a[href^='/introduction-to-selenium']
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  //a[starts-with(@href, '/introduction-to-selenium') and contains(., 'Introduction')]
  ```

---

### Outro

[selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **contains** also in xpath to identify the tag.

eg : //a[contains(text(),'Introduction')]

There should not be multiple "Introduction" in the page.