# CSS selector that can work with text in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

Hi I want to perform my action on a web element in List with the desired text 
I am able to achieve this xpath as mentioned below:

Xpath:    //span[contains(text(),'Listitem3')]

However as per instruction not to use xpath so i am looking for CSS selector that can work with text 
I tried with 
cssSelector:   span:contains(Listitem3)

However this is not working.
Please anyone help to create and find a valid cssSelector for my scenario

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception/47884814#47884814) helps you?

Comment: No @DebanjanB that query is resolved with xpath only and we cannot use xpath for same.

Comment: If you can update the question with some more of the outerHTML of the `<span>` element, I will give it a try.