# How to locate element using text() facing exception(selenium+python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

HTML

```
<span class="menu-text">Download App</span>
```

my code to locate the element

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//span[contains(text(),'App')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//span[contains(.,'App')]")
```

when I run it, an exception reported:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "//span[contains(text(),'App')]" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: '//span[contains(text(),'App')]' is not a valid selector: "//span[contains(text(),'App')]"
```

Comment: since your using a xpath expression, use driver.find_element_by_xpath instead

Answer (score 6):

Since your using a xpath expression, use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'App')]")
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You Are Giving `Xpath` to `css` selector it's wrong!

you need to give `xpath` to `xpath` function not `css selector` function

That's Why You Are Getting That Error

Try This:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'App')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "//span[contains(text(),'App')]" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: '//span[contains(text(),'App')]' is not a valid selector: "//span[contains(text(),'App')]"
```

...implies that the **css selector expression** which you have used is not a valid **css selector**.

---

Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) to locate element by **text** is not supported through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) yet (although it may work in the developer tools console). The only possibility is [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)

You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

---

So using `css_selectors` as per the HTML you have provided you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
span.menu-text
```

However your code trials pretty much resembles to *xpath*. So you need to change `find_element_by_css_selector` to `find_element_by_xpath`. So effectively, the line of code will be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Download App']")
```

As an alternative,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'App')]")
```