# How to find element by css selector witch contains attribute and text

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

```
<span _ngcontent-c77="" class="status-label success" tooltipcontainer="body" tooltipheader="Error" tooltipmode="click" tooltipposition="top" data-test-id="status"> online </span>
```

In xpath i can find this element by

```
//*[@data-test-id="status" and text()=" online "]
```

But i can't understand how to find this element with containing text ' online ' using css selector. Help me with this, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with `css_selector`, `xpath` is the only way to locate by text. There is `find_element_by_link_text`, but only for `<a>` tags, and without additional attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because Selenium supports CSS2, and `contains()` is CSS3. You can find detailed information [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/css-selector-using-contains-fails-with-invalid-element-state-failed-to-exec)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to locate an element by [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) using the `innerText` i.e. `contains('string')`. You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with "span:contains('string')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814).

To locate an element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR` 1:

  ```
  span.status-label.success[tooltipcontainer='body'][tooltipheader='Error']
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR` 2:

  ```
  span[data-test-id='status'][tooltipcontainer='body'][tooltipheader='Error']
  ```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible.

But i think you can use the "data-"

Copy content from you span to data:
**data-text="online"**

For example:

```
<span _ngcontent-c77="" data-text="online" class="status-label success" tooltipcontainer="body" tooltipheader="Error" tooltipmode="click" tooltipposition="top" data-test-id="status"> online </span>
```

And CSS:

```
/* Select every cell containing "Online" */
span[data-text*="online"] {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: There is no `data-text` attribute in the html.

Comment: i know, but its is a solution is necessary add this atribute. Just with CSS this is unique way

Comment: So he need to locate the element, add the attribute, and then locate it again?