# VBA to find if an element contains certain texts

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm new to Selenium and VBA.
What i want to do is automate selection of a certain TEXT in a CSS.
Selenium brings me this:

```
css=.x-grid3-row:nth-child(42) .x-grid3-col:nth-child(4) > .x-grid3-cell-inner
```

Everyting would be fine, except the TEXT I want to select sometimes move to different `grid3-row:nth-child`
What I want to achieve is to find in which `x-grid3-row:nth-child` the desired TEXT is so I could click it with a VBA bot.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to construct a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) passing the desired text.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

As an alternative you can use a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner' and text()='certain_text']")
```

Comment: that actually really helped. But another problem popped out. I did find my desired text, but it turns out that it can't be clicked, instead there is a cell-inner in the next grid column. Sadly i can't find any similarities of the mentioned grid with the desired text. How to keep the targeted row with the desired text and target the nearby column?

Comment: @baxius That sounds to be a different question all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?