# VBA selenium to click on a nearby grid column

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

A problem derived from my previous question:" [VBA to find if an element contains certain texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532038/vba-to-find-if-an-element-contains-certain-texts)"
I find the desired text using :

```
 driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner' and text()='TEXT']")
```

but it is unclickable.  The box in the next column is where i want to click.
How to click a nearby grid column ?

[image: Ca72-4]

Ca72-4 is what i try to find.
The grid row of Ca72-4 may differ.
Path of the text (in selenium) :

```
xpath=//div[42]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div
```

The yellow box on the right is input.
Path of the desired target (in selenium) :

```
 xpath=//div[42]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` in the adjascent cell next to the text **Ca72-4** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner' and text()='Ca72-4']//following::td[1]/div").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to dim an integer and to loop and check all div[#] and then use the integer with targets xpath. But i'd really like to avoid loops if possible.